# Is there a method to pass the text value through the code depending on the radiobutton click?

Tags: java, android, xml, textview, radio-button

[UPDATE: This query is solved through other means]
I have tried writing 2 codes which I will be adding here. It's not showing any errors but the application stops immediately after Run. I am trying to pass text value via `TextView` when the user clicks on the `Radiobutton` from the `RadioGroup`.As a beginner, I am unable to find the correct method still. Are my methods correct? Which methods can I use to correct this issue?

I don't want to use a button and Toast. I only want to use a component which will display the value stored in it through the code. Other methods gave me errors, so I am attaching the two Java codes which did not pop up errors.

**Code 1:**

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.RadioButton;

import android.widget.RadioGroup;

import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RadioGroup radiogroup1;

    RadioButton no;
    RadioButton yes;

   TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

   @Override

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       yes =(RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.yes);

       no = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.no);

       RadioGroup radioGroup1 = findViewById(R.id.radiogroup1);


   };


   public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
       boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
       String str;
       str = "";
       // Check which radio button was clicked
       switch (view.getId()) {
           case R.id.yes:
               if (checked)
                   str = "Hold on";
               txt.setText(str);
               break;
           case R.id.no:
               if (checked)
                   str = "Fine go now";
               txt.setText(str);
               break;
       }

   }


}
```

**Code 2**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  RadioGroup radiogroup1;

 RadioButton yes;
 RadioButton no;

   TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

   @Override

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       yes =(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.yes);
       no = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.no);

       RadioGroup radioGroup1 = findViewById(R.id.radiogroup1);

       radiogroup1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

           @Override
           public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {


  int index = radiogroup1.indexOfChild(radiogroup1);

               String str="";
               switch (index) {
                   case 0:

                       str = "Hold on";
                       txt.setText(str);
                       break;

                   case 1:

                       str = "Fine go";
                       txt.setText(str);
                       break;

               }
           }
       });


   }
}
```

The different text will be displayed for both `RadioButtons`.

Answer (score 0):

Above method which you have mentioned is correct .

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RadioGroup radiogroup1;

RadioButton no;
RadioButton yes;
TextView txt ;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   yes =(RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.yes);
   no = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.no);
   RadioGroup radioGroup1 = findViewById(R.id.radiogroup1);
   txt= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1)

};


public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
   boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
   String str;
   str = "";
   // Check which radio button was clicked
   switch (view.getId()) {
       case R.id.yes:
           if (checked)
               str = "Hold on";
           break;
       case R.id.no:
           if (checked)
               str = "Fine go now";
           break;
   }
           txt.setText(str);

}

}
```

Comment: Did you run it on your system? Because it did not work for me so I asked here.

Answer (score 0):

Provide your error so we can actually see where the problem is.

Anyways this code snippet will work:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
implements View.OnClickListener {

private TextView tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RadioButton radio1 = findViewById(R.id.radio_1);
    RadioButton radio2 = findViewById(R.id.radio_2);

    radio1.setOnClickListener(this);
    radio2.setOnClickListener(this);

    tv = findViewById(R.id.main_text_view);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    String text;
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.radio_1:
            text = "button1";
            tv.setText(text);
            break;

        case R.id.radio_2:
            text = "button2";
            tv.setText(text);
            break;
    }
}
}
```